# Remove everything after the first instance of one of several characters

Tags: javascript, string

Say I have a string like:

`var str = "Good morningX Would you care for some tea?"`

Where the `X` could be one of several characters, like a `.`, `?`, or `!`.

How can I remove everything after that character?
If it could only be one type of character, I would use `indexOf` and `substr`, but it looks like I need a different method to find the position in this case. Perhaps a regular expression?

**Clarification:** I do not know what character X is. I'd like to cut the string off at the first occurrence of any one of the specified characters.

**Ok, further clarification:**

What I'm actually doing is scrubbing posts from a website. I'm taking the first bit from each post and stitching them together. By 'bit', I mean characters before the first piece of punctuation. I need to cut everything off after that punctuation. Does that make sense?

Comment: Are you looking for `split()`

Comment: does X mean "any character that is not a letter or number"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just replace everything within the `[` and `]` with your delimiters. Escape if necessary.

```
var str = "Good morning! Would you care for some tea?";
var beginning = str.split(/[.?!]/)[0];
// "Good morning"
```

Comment: This seems to look though the entire string for each of the specified characters and only move onto the next if the previous one is not found. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. It looks through the entire string, and matches on any of the possibilities. The `[0]` part returns just the first match. Without that, you'd have an array that looks like `["Good morning", "Would you care for some tea", ""]`.

Comment: Is there a way to check for each character at the same time so that, for instance, if there's a question mark before a comma, it will cut at the question mark?

Comment: So, you mean, only if there is a question mark before a comma? You'd need to use a lookahead to do that. So, if you wanted to cut on "?," or "!," or ".,", you could use a regex like `/[.?!](?=,)/`. If that's not what you're looking for, I'll probably need to see an additional example.

Comment: @kalley It would mess up if you want to split with single separator.It will split based on all /[.?!]/`.

Comment: @kalley See question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, If the X have this ',' character , then try below

```
var s = 'Good morning, would you care for some tea?';
s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(','));
document.write(s);
```

Demo  : http://jsfiddle.net/L4hna/490/

and if the X have '!' , then try below

```
var s = 'Good morning! would you care for some tea?';
s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('!'));
document.write(s);
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/L4hna/491/

Try this way for your requirement string.

Both are will return Good Morning

Comment: Right you are, but I need to check for them all at the same time. In your method it will be cut off at the comma, even if the exclamation mark comes first in the string.

Comment: You can add more special char in there .

Answer (score 0):

The below code will do as you expect:

```
 var s = "Good morningX Would you care for some tea?";
  s = s.substring(X, n != -1 ? n : s.length);
  document.write(s);
```

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/JEFnY/

The regex would be

`str.replace(/(.*?)([\.\?\!])(.*)/i, '$1$2');`

The first capturing group is a lazy expression to match everything before the next capturing group.

The second capturing group only looks for the characters that you specify - which in this case are `.!?`, all escaped.

The last capturing group is discarded. Hence the substitution string is `$1$2`, or the first two capturing groups together.